# UITableView Custom Class not showing results

Tags: swift

I have a ViewController on the storyboard.

TestViewController.swift

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

var users : Dictionary = [String:User]()

let customTableView : UITableView = UITableView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    customTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "userCell")
    let customTable = CustomTable(users:users)
    customTableView.delegate = customTable
    customTableView.dataSource = customTable

    view.addSubview(customTableView)

    customTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    customTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    customTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    customTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    customTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

}

}
```

CustomTable.swift

```
class CustomTable: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var users : Dictionary = [String:User]()
var userNames = ["Steve", "Joe", "Bob"]
var userIds = [String]()

init(users: [String:User]) {


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("HEY")
    return userNames.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    print("HIHI")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userCell", for: indexPath)

    let text = userNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = text

    return cell

}

}
```

`numberOfRowsInSection` - seems to fire
`cellForRowAt` - doesn't fire / print "HIHI", therefore, my table is empty.

I have moved creating the table to `viewDidAppear`, nothing.

I have searched tirelessly to find similar situations, but nothing seems to solve it. Does anything stick out to anyone or have done this successfully?

Comment: Looks like pretty standard stuff. Is there a reason you're not using `UITableViewController`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am using this to add multiple table views to the screen, I already have a main table view setup in my app. Ex. this would be for a dropdown with a table of users to select from. Just trying to get this very basic instance to work then going to build on it.

Comment: What is the value of `userNames.count` ?

Comment: 3. I can hard code it to 3 and still same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare customTable reference at class level. It becomes nil as soon as it leaves the scope of viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry, I'm not following. How do you do that?

Comment: I see what you mean now... move let customTable : CustomTable = CustomTable() outside viewDidLoad

Comment: var customTable: CustomTable! outside viewDidLoad. Then you can define that variable inside viewDidLoad. Make sure you define it before using.